# How do we set docker containers to restart on reboot and on-failure?

Tags: docker, monitor, systemd

I would like the docker containers to come up

1. On `host reboot` or when `docker is restarted` on host
2. `On failure` with `maximum retries` .

I am aware that the docker restart policies `unless-stopped` and `always` are in the same direction but I would want them to fail after maximum retries.

Thinking of below steps as a solution

1. `No restart policy` on docker containers
2. `systemd-docker` to restart containers `on-failure` and enabled on reboot.

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the docker containers to come up On host reboot **or when docker is restarted on host**

This is not a complete answer, but know that docker 1.12 will add a [daemonless container](https://github.com/crosbymichael/docker/blob/d705dab1b1bd0a946d647374325d61fac57736db/docs/admin/configuring.md#daemonless-containers) mode
([PR 23213](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23213)):

> ### Daemonless Containers
>
> Starting with Docker 1.12 containers can run without Docker or `containerd` running.
>   This allows the Docker daemon to exit, be upgraded, or recover from a crash without affecting running containers on the system.
>
> To enable this functionality you need to add the `--live-restore` flag when launching `dockerd`. This will ensure that Docker does not kill containers on graceful shutdown or on restart leaving the containers running.